# Integer not written to label

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

```
if (combostyle.getSelectedItem().equals(" ") || (comboSize.getSelectedItem().equals(" ")) || (comboclr.getSelectedItem().equals(" ")) ) {
    lblqtot.setText(String.valueOf("Please complete the form"));           
}

else if (comboquant.getSelectedItem().equals("15")) {
    int totals = Integer.parseInt(lblTotal.getText());
    int quantity = 15;

            int total = totals * quantity;
            String total2 = String.valueOf(total);

            lblqtot.setText(total2);
            label1.setText(total2);
              repaint();
              this.repaint();
              super.repaint();
                   }
}
```

Having an issue in that the label for the total (lblqtot) isn't written to with the value of total2 - Basically, I have a total price that I need to multiply by the combo box, so if the combo box selection (for quantity) is equal to 15, then the total is multiplied by 15 to give the grand total.
Hope that this makes sense...

At the moment however, absolutely nothing happens with the label, and yet I get no errors?

Comment: if you're an absolute newbie, you should start at the beginning, not with GUI's. That being said: does this code execute, or does the first if block execute, (or does this condition return to false) ?
what is label1? is it set to visible? 
you may want to show a bit more code and context.

Comment: Are you sure that `total` has a value?

Comment: What thread is this running on? There is a specific thread for updating the UI.

Comment: @Stultuske - Sadly, need to do a GUI for my assignment at college (I know, bloody ridiculous) ... The first IF block does not execute, no. label1 is actually the AWT label that I attempted for the same job as a friend said that it may be that the Jlabel is not capable of the task.

Comment: @Rich - I honestly haven't a clue! I didn't understand that there were specific threads?

Comment: @Drumnbass honestly it could be that since total is the value of a label, and the .getvalue method is returning errors, that this does not have a value, any ideas with this one? (good thinking actually! I forgot about that if I am honest.)

Comment: @PhilMarsh Unfortunately, there are no easy shortcuts. If your assignment is to do a minimal GUI; well, then that is your assignment. And that means: start with basic tutorials, build super-small applications; and start adding the things you need in order to fulfill your assignment. And when you are stuck, provide a minimal example of the code that doesn't work. From here, most likely you update the jlabel content; but you don't enforce the UI to repaint.

Comment: To help you we need a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you post the code related to the layout design?

Comment: put some logs and try

Comment: @Jägermeister - That's a good point, I haven't been told about repainting the UI - so I will google this and look into it (thanks for that buddy!)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I appologize, the code is messy as hell to be honest, that's why I kept it minimal. I will add the entire Code block for the if statement if you wish?

Comment: @MChaker It's very long and messy (see above comment)

Comment: @PhilMarsh The problem is, that we need the complete code, because the error may be everywhere

Comment: @PhilMarsh: why are you using awt? at the very least you should be using Swing.

Comment: @maraca - wow, can't believe I didn't even try that one, I'll have a look!

Comment: @maraca - no luck with that one, same problem. Jlabel isn't updating and there are no errors in the code

Comment: @Stultuske - Recommendation of the teacher (for the label) - the application and the label I am trying to write to IS swing. :)

Comment: Using repaint doesn't seem to work either. Getting confused here!

Comment: @PhilMarsh: hate to tell you, but your education is lousy at best. writing gui's at the very beginning? using awt components while there are Swing alternatives .... Hope you don't mind me telling this, though, seems like you are really into it, but don't restrict your learning process to only this teacher's courses.

Comment: all 3 code lines about repaint(); talking about the issue is elsewhere,

Comment: @PhilMarsh Probably the shortest solution `.equals(new Integer(15))` (or see answer for alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be with your JLabel - it doesn't get updated, even if you assigned a new value to it. The JLabel lives inside a JFrame, which , once created, tends to keep its elements as they are. What you need to do is refresh the frame:

`frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();`

Comment: non-static method invalidate() cannot be converted from a static context?

Comment: @PhilMarsh It seems that you wrote something like JFrame.invalidate() ... that doesn't work. You need to call these methods on the JFrame **object** that you created. Long story short: you should **better** spend the next hours reading AWT/Swing tutorials. Otherwise you are expecting people here to teach you each and any step required to get your work done. Do you really think that would be the best use of your (and other peoples) time?

Comment: read chapter 9 - 'User Interface Components with Swing'  : http://www.dcc.ufrj.br/~comp2/TextosJava/CJ1.pdf  ; btw, i recommend reading the entire book

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you call `getSelectedItem()` which returns an `Object`. Either you can transform this to an `int` (e.g. `((Integer)comboquant.getSelectedItem()).intValue() == 15`) or if the index of the item corresponds to its value then you can use `getSelectedIndex()` (or `getSelectedIndex() + 1` if you start at `1`).

Alternatively if you manage an array with the `int` values like they are in the list then you can just do it like this: `arr[comboStyle.getSelectedIndex()]`

Comment: maraca: I'm not so sure. If you look at: Object c = new Integer(15); sop(c.equals(15)); it will print true. it might be the problem, not saying that, but autoboxing should take care of that.

Comment: @Stultuske no I think in case of objects it would be something like: `((XXX)xxx.getSelectedItem()).getValue()`

Comment: as I said, it is indeed possible. but, as you set, getItem() returns an Object, getValue() returns the String representation.

Comment: @Stultuske this depends on the class `XXX`, you first need to cast the object (`XXX` in the example) and then call the correct method.

Comment: ehm... no, it doesn't. the getSelectedItem() method of JComboBox (what we're talking about) returns an Object ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem() )
This is wath matters, because this is what is being asked. Indeed, for the getValue(), that's dependent of the type, but since this is not really relevant (based on the OP's code) I just picked the example already mentioned before.

Comment: @Stultuske I understood now why you didn't like the example, I added a better one in the answer. Also as you say `.equals(new Integer(15))` should also work if he has Integers.